# How to access data type of a class declared in one class into another class (both in different translation unit)?

Tags: c++

I have 5 files. (1. A.hpp, A.cpp : 2. B.hpp, B.cpp : 3 main.cpp)

```
// A.hpp
#ifndef MY_CLASS_A
#define MY_CLASS_A

#include <iostream>

class B; // forward declaration so that I could do B * b;

struct s {
    int x;
    double y;
};

class A{
    s my_struct;
    int size;
    B * b;
public:
    A(int, double, int);
    void f1(s);
    void f2(); // this function calls B's f1 function
    s get_struct();
    int get_size();
    void print();
};

#endif
```

Then I have its implementation as

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

A::A(int x_, double y_, int size_):my_struct({x_, y_}), size(size_){}  

void A::f1(s s_){
    // do stuff   
    s_.x = 5;
    s_.y = 51.99;
}

void A::f2(){

    int val;   
    // Here I am calling B's f1 function
    val = b->f1(my_struct);

}

s A::get_struct(){

    return my_struct;
}

int A::get_size(){

    return size;
} 

void A::print(){
    std::cout << " ----- " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x    = " << my_struct.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y    = " << my_struct.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size = " << size << std::endl; 
    std::cout << " ----- " << std::endl;
}
```

Then I have B

```
//B.hpp
#ifndef MY_CLASS_B
#define MY_CASS_B

#include "A.hpp" // I placed here A.hpp because I am 
                 // trying to use A's struct type 

class A;

class B{

public:
    int f1(s); // A's struct use here to get struct by value

};

#endif
```

and its implementation as

```
// B.cpp
#include "B.hpp"

 //  used A's struct here again
int B::f1(s my_struct){ 

    std::cout << "*****" << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_struct.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_struct.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*****" << std::endl;
}
```

finally main as

```
// main.cpp
// As per comment I should place #include "A.hpp" here 
#include "A.cpp"

int main(){

    A a(4,9.9, 5);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

My main question is how can I access the struct declared in class A into class B?
I have tried to use forward declaration by failed miserably.

Comment: In your *main* file, I find the `#include "A.cpp"` pretty weird... Did you mean `#include "A.hpp"`?

Comment: @WhiZTiM I do that so that I don't have to do g++ --std=c++11 A.cpp main.cpp .. this way I could directly do g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp

Comment: thats a *weird* practice. Inherently fragile. It's like sitting on a keg of Gunpowder... Kaboom!!. Based on C++'s ODR, you will have issues of multiple definitions if you do that same `#include` in another Translation Unit;

Comment: @pokche Don't do that: it's as bad an idea as it gets.

Comment: I dunno if I'd go that far. I think "Let's invade Russia in the Fall" still has it beat.

Comment: @WhiZTiM I will rectify it from now on

Comment: Probably off topic: Turn up the compiler warning level. `int B::f1(s my_struct)` specified a return type of `int`, yet has no `return` statement. Results of this will be unpredictable

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah that was typo   ... ur world war 2 reference was funny :)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. So turns out I was doing all ok .. except of course what you guys pointed out about #include "A.cpp" .. So I was not compiling correctly .. I was doing $g++ --std=c++11 A.cpp main.cpp In fact I should have done $g++ --std=c++11 A.cpp B.cpp main.cpp . I don't know why I thought of leaving B.cpp behind.

Answer (score 2):

Open your C++ book to the chapter on pointers and references, and read that chapter again.

"The struct declared in class A" is `my_struct`, which is a `private` class member.

To have it accessible elsewhere, you need to pass it by reference.

```
int B::f1(const s &my_struct){ 

    std::cout << "*****" << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_struct.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_struct.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*****" << std::endl;
}
```

Now, when you invoke this from `A`:

```
val = b->f1(my_struct);
```

This will now pass a reference to the `my_struct` member, instead of making a copy of it.

Note that the parameter is declared as a reference to a `const` instance of `s`, because `f1()` does not need to modify it. If it does, simply pass it as a non-const reference:

```
int B::f1(s &my_struct){
```

Now, `f1()` will be able to modify `my_struct`, and end up modifying this private instance of `A`'s class, that was passed to it.

P.S. This has nothing to do with different translation units. Whether this whole thing is in one translation unit, or is split across half a dozen of them, classes and references work the same way.